# Invalid View State. The Client is disconnected

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, iis-7.5

I am getting an error 
**Error Message**: The client disconnected.
**Error Source**: System.Web
**Stack Treace**: System.Web.UI.ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate ...

I have a simple web application running on windows IIS 7.5 framework 4.0. **and there is no load bilancer**
I am opening some pages on overlay using jquery tool of [flowplayer](http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/external.html).

Earlier I was opening the whole page with view-state on the landing page.
e.g.

> ```
> $("a[rel]").length && $("a[rel]").live("click", function (a) {
>         var b = $(this).overlay({
>             mask: "gray",
>             effect: "apple",
>             closeOnClick: !1,
>             closeOnEsc: !1,
>             fixed: !1,
>             top: 0,
>             onBeforeLoad: function () {
>                 var a = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap"),
>                     b = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap_Request"),
>                     d = this.getOverlay().find(".contentWrap_AddLead");
>                 a.html("");
>                 b.html("");
>                 d.html("");
>                 a.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
>                 b.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href"));
> ```

```
            }...
```

I thought the view state of the page which I was loading was causing the problem. So I changed the the code as follows

```
a.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href") + " .ajaxDiv");
b.load(this.getTrigger().attr("href") + " .ajaxDiv");
```

Now,I am not opening the whole page.
For avoiding the view sate of the page which I am opening on overlay I load only a pre define div of the page.

I have search over internet and found some suggestion like specifying the machine key. Which I have put in my web.config file.

```
 <pages enableViewStateMac="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Always"/>
 <machineKey validationKey="...." decryptionKey="..." validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" /> 
 <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms requireSSL="true" protection="All" timeout="720" defaultUrl="...." loginUrl="Default.aspx" >
        </forms>
    </authentication>
```

But still I am getting the error above mention.
I have seen on blog suggesting [Check HttpResponse.IsClientConnected in page load event](http://rayaspnet.blogspot.in/2010/12/how-to-fix-invalid-viewstate-and.html)
Should I use this method. The traffic on my application is not too much It is around 7 to 9 thousand per day (24 hours). So can there be any reason of  Application Pool Recycling.

I have also seen article of Stack [Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8252276/system-web-ui-viewstateexception-invalid-viewstate) but no luck.
Also I would like to add that 4 application are running in the same application pool in which my application is running.

Comment: see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809413/what-might-be-causing-thethe-client-disconnected-asp-net-exception


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809413/what-might-be-causing-thethe-client-disconnected-asp-net-exception